# How to open and display documents(.pdf, .doc, docx) from device without external app in Xamarin Android?

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, doc

I'm using Xamarin Forms ver 2.4.

I have a problem when display documents(.pdf, .doc, docx) from device

Could you share me how to implement for Android to display documents in offline mode without external app?

Comment: You will either need to write your own rendering engine for those document types, or find a library or tool that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

That is not something that is supported in Xamarin.Forms by default. You will either have to write your own component to render each format you want to support or find a control that already does this.

I know [SyncFusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin) has a solution for this.

Another thing you could try is maybe opening the files in a browser control. Maybe they will be able to render some of it, but that's more a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use third party component in the project. So far, I still have the problem when display doc,docx file on Xamarin Android. Could you show me any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I would suggest you do it like would be in a WebView using Google Docs viewer.

```
public class PdfWebViewClient : WebViewClient   {                       
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)                         
{         return true;      }                       }   
private WebView pdfViewr;   
/// //You should put the below code where you initialize your Views/Controls     
//Probably OnCreate or OnCreateView /// pdfViewr = 
 view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.pdfViewer);  
pdfViewr.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;    
pdfViewr.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;  
pdfViewr.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;    
pdfViewr.Settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);            
 //pdfViewr.SetWebViewClient = new AsyncCallback             
pdfViewr.SetWebViewClient(new PDFWebViewClient());                                   
var link = "your_document_path";  
pdfViewr.LoadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + link);
```

I recently used it for PDF but im pretty sure other docs would work too.

In case it doesn't revert.

Comment: Thank you! If I use Google Docs viewer, the device have to online on Internet. But I want to display documents in Offline mode. I found the solution to display .pdf file on Xamarin Android. https://github.com/jfversluis/pdfjs
So far, I still have the problem when display doc,docx file on Xamarin Android. Could you show me any solutions?